# Linux kernel driver async I2C (on Raspberry PI)

Tags: linux, asynchronous, driver, nonblocking, i2c

I'd like to write an I2C driver for a sensor device. There is a non-zero conversion time, and I don't want to waste kernel time to wait and poll busy state until the device is busy.

I thought I setup a timer and call the update time to time.

However the whole system freezes when execution reaches any I2C function.

I prepared a really simplified example, which is not working. Everything fine until the I2C access.

http://pastebin.com/kP5LCK2c

Without I2C stuff, the code works. Without the timer stuff, I2C works.

I did not find how to use I2C in an asynchronous (non-blocking) manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the i2c functions sleep, they can't be called from a timer. Luckily, timers aren't the only way to schedule work into the future. Look at work queues:

- [LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-6)
- [How to use Linux Work Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937245/how-to-use-linux-work-queue)

In particular, look at `queue_delayed_work`, which will allow you to run a function in the future, in a process context able to sleep.

Comment: I implemented it using `queue_delayed_work` but the result is identical. The whole machine freezes every single case when execution reaches I2C communication.

Comment: For a sanity check, can you talk to the I2C device from userspace? Also, what happens if you try to do a read during the device probe.

Comment: I can use the device from both user and kernel space, if there is no timer / work queue. Even the I2C read/write in probe works, and everything is fine until the update function called by the timer / work queue.

Comment: The result after the timer / wq calls the update function is an oops:

http://pastebin.com/JzDmDmuC

Comment: That's a simple null pointer dereference. Probably `test114_i2c` is null. Two things to try: `printk` the pointer value before using it, and be sure you initialise the variable before you queue the first work item.

Comment: Well, meanwhile I found it is trivially my fault. During the heavy development I removed a `return 0;` from the code (`test114_probe`). 

Hence it ran further and reached a kfree() - which freed a client data structure, which contains mutex data and others.

So, with `queue_delayed_work` it works correctly.

Thanks for the help!